# Radicale running in local network, though not reachable from laptop

Tags: server, raspbian-stretch, services

Obviously, I am a complete beginner in setting up a server. That is why I started to play around with a raspberry pi in the first place. I already managed to set up some `smb` shares.

I am trying for days to set up [`radicale`](http://radicale.org/), as described in the [official basic setup](http://radicale.org/setup/) using bycrypt and system-wide systemd. `radicale` is already running on the pi (`systemctl status radicale`) and the chosen port is also visible, though using the ip `127.0.0.1` but as far as I understand [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20778887), it should be fine.

Note that I am using a headless setup with `raspbian stretch` on the `pi3`, connected to the local network via `wifi` and I have `no fixed ip` assigned. Note also that I extended the range of my router using another one by configuring it as WAP.